# How to define log file in IIS with fields separated by commas

Tags: iis, logging, windows-server

I want to define a log file for a site in IIS. I want to choose which fields I want and they need to be separated by commas. The format IIS is separated by commas but I can't choose the fields and the format W3C let me choose the fields but they're separated by commas. I also search how to do custom log files and found the Advanced loggin plugin but I can't find any option for the separation of fields.

Does anyone knows how to define a log file with personalized fields and separated by commas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you want to use commas? Almost all data analysis tools support importing W3C format log files.

Comment: @LexLi I just want to know who is accessing the site and to export the log file to a excell file. But can you give me a name of a tool for data analysis? Thank you for your help

Comment: SQL Server Express or tools for IIS log specifically. Even Excel can import W3C files.